# How to make heat equation dimensionless for neural network in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I am trying to use PyTorch for making a Physics Informed Neural Network for the heat equation in 1D:

[image]

I tried the following code to make a loss function for PDE residual:

```
def lossPDE(self,x_PDE):
    g = x_PDE.clone()
    g.requires_grad = True # Enable differentiation
    f = self.forward(g)
    f_x_t = torch.autograd.grad(f,g,torch.ones([g.shape[0],1]).to(device),retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0] # first derivative of time
    f_xx_tt = torch.autograd.grad(f_x_t,g,torch.ones(g.shape).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]#second derivative of x
    f_t = f_x_t[:,[1]]
    f_xx = f_xx_tt[:,[0]]
    f = f_t - alpha * f_xx
    return self.loss_function(f,f_hat) # f_hat is a tensor of zeros and it minimizes the f value
```

In the simulation I am making a one day simulation (86400 seconds) for a bar with the length of 1 meters. Now, I want to make my PDE dimensionless. How can I do it in pytorch? Which part of my code should be changed? The unit of alpha is already in `m2/s`. I can share my whole code but it would be hundreds lines of code.
I very much appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a simple fraction like `(predicted_value-expected_value)/expected_value` that, by definition is dimensionless, supposing the two are in the same units of measure?
Many approaches are possible based on the same principle.

Comment: Dear @decadenza, Thanks for dedicating time to my issue. Where should I put the fraction? A FE solver is giving me simulation results for a 86400 second time in a 1 m bar. Then, I use these data to train and test the network. So, where can I put the fraction you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my previous comment to answer.

As long as you make use of PyTorch operators (which take care of gradients), you can define a generic Python function that takes the truth value `y` and the predicted value `yhat` in input and returns a number.

Very broadly:

```
def my_basic_loss(y, yhat):
    loss = torch.mean(torch.abs(y - yhat)/torch.abs(y))
    return loss
```

Or you can consider quadratic values (probably better).

No need to manually call `autograd`.

For other operations you should extend PyTorch instead.
See [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-functions/29387) for extra details.

Comment: I think the question is about Physics-informed neural network. Just to clarify, the expected values of PDE is 0. Because we [minimise the potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_total_potential_energy_principle) of the system which is PDE in this case. 
The question was pretty much redundant. One thing the OP could do is [non-dimensionalise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa28ifA7H9o) the problem not the PDE.